# Applications of forcing to Topology

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, forcing

I'm insterested on set theory and general topology: particulary on forcing and compactness. I'm searching for a book which study the interaction between both topics or even the interaction between Set-Theoretic Topology and Forcing in general. Can some one recommend me some online material, book or paper?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are several surveys by Alan Dow at his homepage http://math2.uncc.edu/~adow/Surveys.html there is much more by various authors, a complete answer could be much longer

Comment: You may also be interested in the paper http://www.math.toronto.edu/tall/publications/UsefulModel.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the (excellent but outdated) handbook of set theoretic topology and then move onto (recently revised) open problems in set theoretic topology. This has evolved into a vast subject so it is hard to recommend specific papers too strongly. My advice is: Learn the basic techniques (elementary submodels, forcing, combinatorial principles), fall in love with a problem (there are plenty) and solve it! Good luck.